# $K$-Automorphisms of finite field Extension $L/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension $[L:K]= n$ and $\alpha \in L$ s.t for $K$-Automorphisms $\sigma_1, ... \sigma_n$ of $L$, it holds that $\sigma_i(\alpha) \neq \sigma_j(\alpha)$ for all $i \neq j$. Show that $L = K(\alpha)$.

I received a hint to look at the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Let $f \in K[X]$ be the minimalpolynomial of $\alpha \in L$. Clearly $K(\alpha) \subset L$, so we can restrict $\sigma_i$ to $\sigma'_i := \sigma_i|_{K(\alpha)}$. Now for every $i \in \{1, ... ,n\}$ we have that $\sigma'_i(\alpha)$ is a root in $L$ of $f$. Since $\sigma'_i(\alpha) \neq \sigma'_j(\alpha)$ for $i \neq j$, $f$ has exactly $n$ roots in $L$.

Now, does it follow that $\sigma_i = \sigma'_i$ for all $i$, so $K(\alpha) = L$? I'm not sure how to finish the proof here.

Comment: No, the chain of reasoning is somewhat different – basically, all the $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ are distinct roots of $f$ so $f$ has degree $n$. Therefore $[K(\alpha):K]=n$, and as $K \subset K(\alpha) \subset L$ with $[L:K]=n$, $L=K(\alpha)$.

Comment: You're right. Thank you!